# What type of paint to use for a bike frame

Tags: paint, customization

What's the best type of paint to use for painting bike frames, it's steel if that makes a difference?

I want to do a custom paint job and mix a few colours in a gradient effect. Should I use enamel paid, or an off the shelf car paint etc?

Also what paint should I use for an undercoat, a car primer paint ??

many thanks

Comment: Starter: Hardwearing/durable/abrasion resistant, waterproof, oilproof, and compatible with the frame materials.

Comment: There is a specific easy paint for this called Spray.Bike but it is not as hard wearing as a proper 2k or baked enamel finish. However it's cheap and designed for purpose and i believe genuinely unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically any paint that could be used on a car will work on a steel bike frame.

The better the paint the more robust it will be. Two-part epoxy based paints or powder coating are probably your best bets, but require specialized equipment. I think there are epoxy paints that do not require curing in an oven but you still need a spray gun.

You can probably use aerosol can paint with a self etching primer, meticulous preparation and good technique.

Comment: [appliance spray paint](https://www.google.com/search?q=appliance+spray+paint&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1)

Comment: @Mazura you should make that an answer and explain why you think it would work well for a bike.

Comment: It's epoxy paint in a spray can; you don't need a gun.

Comment: @Mazura, Is it really epoxy though?. Two-part epoxy paint is mixed before spraying and then cures by a chemical process (often assisted by an oven). Anything that comes out of a spray can must dry by evaporation of a solvent.

Comment: It *says* epoxy on the can but I'm not actually sure. Nevermind anyway, it says it's for interior only. However, if I had to choose an aerosol can that would still be it. But no matter what you use the absolute key is meticulous surface preparation.

Comment: @Mazura agree with your last point for sure

Answer (score 5):

Car paints will work fine, and car primers. There is one brand of paint that comes in rattle-cans and is specifically marketed for repainting bikes.

You could get a powdercoating shop to lay down a base coat--that would probably be inexpensive, and give you a durable protective layer under whatever paint you applied.

Comment: After the frame has been powder coated, threads, especially the bottom bracket, may need to be recut.

Comment: Excellent point. Probably just chased, not recut, but I agree.

Comment: With proper masking, the threads inside the BB shell should be fine. Facing the shell, sure, but it would need to be a half-assed powdercoating job if you need to chase the threads.

Answer (score 1):

Eastwood makes a 2k primer & clear coat so I've already primed it with their 2k spray and I plan on mixing my own liquid acrylic and sealing it with the
2k clear coat.